# Site self-evaluation - how are you doing?

Tags: discussion

Here at Stack Exchange we are all about making the Internet better by giving great answers to awesome questions. We do our best to create self-sufficient, self-organizing communities of experts and enthusiasts.

Periodically taking a critical look at the questions and answers is a big part of that. Meta sites often see people discussing specific questions that have been closed to determine whether or not they can (or should) be reopened, but it's rare that anyone looks at questions that are open and answered. Are they better than what the Internet has to offer?  *Are* we making the Internet better?

We're trying out a few ways to get that kind of conversation started in our communities.

Below you'll find ten questions, picked at random from Fitness & Nutrition. Please take a look at each, and try to find the answer on Google - then compare what you find to the answer(s) given here. Leave comments and votes here to let everyone know whether Google has a leg up on us here, if we are way more awesome than any other site, or if we're somewhere in-between.

The goal here is for you to gauge how much effort you'd have to put in to answer the question if SE wasn't around and how the results stack up.

Thanks and have fun!

Comment: Looking at this sample is kind of depressing...

Comment: I think one reason many of these questions turned out poorly is the surprisingly strong tendency of F&N.SE to a fewer number of answers. It's common to see only one answer, or only one really quality answer, instead of three or four.

Answer (score 2):

[Is running on treadmills easier than running outdoors because the ground is pulled beneath the runner?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5288/is-running-on-treadmills-easier-than-running-outdoors-because-the-ground-is-pull)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Answer (score 1):

[How do I increase my stamina for dancing?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/how-do-i-increase-my-stamina-for-dancing)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Answer (score 0):

[Eating before/after an evening workout?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5256/eating-before-after-an-evening-workout)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Answer (score 0):

[StrongLifts suggestions for women](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/stronglifts-suggestions-for-women)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Answer (score 0):

[How should I prepare for a marathon on an elliptical machine?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/how-should-i-prepare-for-a-marathon-on-an-elliptical-machine)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Answer (score -2):

[Am I taking too many vitamins and supplements?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/taking-too-many-vitamins-and-supplements)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Comment: The problem here isn't just the answers, its a bad topic, because its almost impossible to give a conclusive answer when it comes to stuff like vitamin. Either way, I think the answers suck no matter what Google brings up

Answer (score -2):

[Power while swimming?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5260/power-while-swimming)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Comment: While the question is highly technical, its asking for a measure that's very very hard to quantify and pretty useless at that. So I don't think any answer would satisfy this one and I don't think you can Google it either

Answer (score -3):

[talking to others at a gym](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/talking-to-others-at-a-gym)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Comment: On an expert site about "physical fitness"? Seems like this should have been closed, much less up-voted. Thumbs down.

Comment: Your wish is my command @RobertCartaino, I would love to enforce more quality, but at this rate it would really just be us mods calling the shots, not a pleasant situation

Comment: @Ivo No, I agree. The mods shouldn't have to be doing this stuff.

Answer (score -3):

[Best nutrition-rich supplement for daily living](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/best-nutrition-rich-supplement-for-daily-living)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Comment: Again a question that's asking for some panacea, which obviously doesn't exist.

Answer (score -3):

[Is biltong healthy for a lean muscle weight trainer?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5298/is-biltong-healthy-for-a-lean-muscle-weight-trainer)

Upvote for "we are better than Google", downvote for "Google wins", and don't vote for "we're about equal".

Comment: Yet another example of what the problem with nutrition is. No real way to give a great answer and the question is singling out a rather localized item in a diet. #fail